# unable to get metadata from jcenter

Tags: android, react-native, maven, gradle, jcenter

Error getting while creating release build in react native

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-community_clipboard:verifyReleaseResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-community_clipboard:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_clipboard
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Error found during release build in react native

Answer (score 1):

Currently jcenter down

Solution
try replace `jCenter()` to `mavenCentral()` to your project gradle

```
 repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. try using AndroidX. it won't resolve

Answer (score 1):

As from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31165#issuecomment-990718123), replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` in your android/app/build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, based on [the posted issue on Github](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia/issues/1039) a temporary solution could be like the following on the `android/build.gradle` file:

```
all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
  if(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
    def url = repo.url.toString()
    if (url.startsWith('https://jcenter.bintray.com/')) {
      remove repo
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, it was happing in one of `node_modules`'s package and I used [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to keep the solution in the production.